# API for top bitcoin addresses sorted by available balance

Tags: address, api

Is there any API from where I can get the list of top bitcoin addresses sorted by available balance? I know there are many websites out there listing Bitcoin rich list but I need an API.

Answer (score 2):

This should works: http://www.tokenview.com:8088/address/richrange/btc/1/100

API documentation: https://tokenview.com/en/api